# Lower bound on the ground state of 2D s-wave with a radial potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, coordinate-systems, schroedinger-equation, ground-state

Consider a Hamiltonian $H = -\Delta + V(r)$ in two dimensions, i.e. $L^2(\mathbb{R^2})$, where $V(r)$ is a smooth and bounded radial and **non-positive** potential. Let me define $\phi(r)$ as my wave function. If I denote $\psi(r) = \sqrt{r}\phi(r)$, then I can write $s$-wave (eigenvalue) Schrödinger equation as:
$$ \left[ \left(-\frac{d^2}{dr^2} - \frac{1/4}{r^2}\right) + V(r) + k^2\right]\psi(r)=0 $$
with a Dirichlet boundary conditions. Here is my confusion: On one hand, because of the presence of the term $\frac{1/4}{r^2}$, I expect we do not have any lower bound for the ground state. On the other hand, in $-\Delta + V(r)$, I know that $-\Delta$ is positive definite and so a lower bound for the ground state shall be the minimum of $V(r)$.
Note that in three (or one) dimensional case, we do not have the term $\frac{1/4}{r^2}$. I appreciate any help.

Comment: A negative number and a positive number can sum up to a positive number. If both are positive, the sum is too automatically, but the converse is not true. The same applies for operators. For functions which give a large negative contribution of the $-1/r^2$ term, the $-(d/dr)^2$ will compensate since $-\Delta$ is non negative. Proving it directly is not obvious though.

Comment: This is not true as far as I know. It is a well-known example that if instead of $\frac{1}{r^2}$, we have had $\frac{1/4 + \epsilon}{r^2}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and even for $V(r) = 0$, the resulting Hamilton, i.e. one-dimensional ODE was unbounded from below. (This example would be corresponding to a 3-dimensional Schrödinger s-wave equation)
https://doi.org/10.1007/s00023-016-0520-7

Comment: This does not contradict my comment. I just claimed that while $-(d/dr)^2$ is non negative and $-1/4r^2$ is non positive, their sum is non negative according to your second argument. Once again, this is not inconsistent with the signs of each of the individual terms. However, if the Laplacian is modified by adding an additional $-\epsilon/r^2$ with $\epsilon>0$, then the new operator is not non negative anymore since the previous inequality was tight in some sense.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I was sloppy and did not explain clearly. The problem is that you are rephrasing my question, not answering it. I know the term $\frac{1}{4r^2}$ comes from laplacian, however, the question is how does it not contradict min-max principle and the minimum of the potential is the lower bound for the ground state? (If it is)